# c# Simple division having issues with messagebox not displaying

Tags: c#, division

Trying to use a button to divide text inputs. I already have the add/sub/mult done and they work fine just the division does not. Below is my code any help is appreciated. The code seems ok my issue is that the messagebox isn't displaying

```
 private void myDivideButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int ans = 0;
        try
        { 
            ans = int.Parse(myInput1.Text) / int.Parse(myInput2.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("The values being divided are " + myInput1.Text + "/" + myInput2.Text + "=" + ans);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            myInput1.Text = "0";
            myInput2.Text = "0";
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: **how** does it "not work"?  Rounding perhaps?  What if the user enters some text like `I like pie` instead of numerals?

Comment: Not getting a message box pop up at all. The other functions work as they should. I click the button and it doesn't display the message box

Comment: if a user enters text the exception changes the values to 0

Comment: Maybe, that `ex` in `catch(ex)` might be holding some clues... Do you know what that section means?

Comment: @MatJ the exception catch is for in the event that a user enters something other than numbers they get switched to a 0 value so that the program does not crash.

Comment: You are swallowing the exception so that you dont even know what "the issue" is  - dont do that.  Exception handling is not for program flow control but for *exceptional* situations and there is nothing special about users providing bad input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The division of 2 integers is an integer. If you want a double-precision floating point number, you have to cast either of the input to a double or decimal. So, if you want a result with decimals, try this:

```
double ans = 0;
try
{
    ans = double.Parse(myInput1.Text) / double.Parse(myInput2.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("The values being divided are " + myInput1.Text + "/" + myInput2.Text + "=" + ans);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    myInput1.Text = "0";
    myInput2.Text = "0";
}
```

Comment: @Chance, what type of number are you typing in and what is the locale/culture of your computer?

Comment: DivideByZeroException is thrown only if the operands are integers (or Decimal). When the operands are real the result of divide by zero is infinity.